# Current location with vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I want to write some code in pure JS.

```
var linx = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar a");

for (var i = 0; i < linx.length; i++) {
  if (linx[i].getAttribute('href') == document.location.pathname) {
    this.className += ' active';
  }
}
```

In console the following

> linx[i].getAttribute('href') == document.location.pathname

outputs `true/false`, so the problem is inside the `if` statement, I just can't get what's wrong.

Comment: Debug the condition: `console.log(i, linx[i].getAttribute('href'), document.location.pathname)`

Comment: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined(…)

Comment: So did you get that error with my code? Did you not place that inside the for loop?

Comment: but on jquery this works   $('a.bx-logo-block').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('href')==document.location.pathname) $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
  });

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to?

Comment: What you mean this? this set to a function, that you call

Comment: sorry, in console: 1 "/uslugi/" "/uslugi/"

Comment: Ah, missed the `this` as @FelixKling pointed out. Good eye!

Comment: ah, i want to refer to this linx[i]

Comment: Then use `linx[i]`, not `this`. `this` most likely refers to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

You problem in 'this' keyword. You should use linx[i].className += ' active';

'this' set to function in which you run your code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this